# Need to set visibility of a Link based on Controller property in ASP.net: MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

In my controller I have a property called BlogCount set to 0 initially:

The controller code :

```
public int BlogCount { get; set; } = 0;
```

The view code :

```
<p style="visibility:hidden;" id="OldBlogs"><a class="btn btn-default" href="">View your old blogs</a></p>
```

and in my view 'Index.cshtml' I have a Link that I need to set the visibility of based on the above property, if BlogCount is greater than 0 it should be visible, else it should be hidden.

I've tried using Javascript :

```
<script>
var prop = '@ViewData["BlogCount"]';
if(prop > 0)
{
$("#OldBlogs").show();
}
else
{
$("#OldBlogs").hide();
}
```

But this doesn't work.

Is this even possible or should I try something else?

edit: Added Controller code

```
public class BlogController : Controller
{
    public int BlogCount = 0;
    // GET: Blog
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Blogs(int id)
    {
        OMSDataContext db = new OMSDataContext();
        Blog blog = new Blog();
        var countrow = from c in db.Blogs
                       where c.UserName == this.User.Identity.Name
                       group c by c.Id into gp
                       select new
                       {
                           Count = gp.Count(),
                       };

        BlogCount =Convert.ToInt32(countrow);
        ViewData["BlogCount"] = 0;           
        //if(blog.UserName == this.User.Identity.Name)
        //{
        //    BlogCount = blog
        //}

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Possible not related: `var prop = '@ViewData["BlogCount"]';` returns `prop` as string. Convert it to integer before doing comparison against zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be simply achieved by using conditional operator like below

```
@{ 
    int BlogCount = (int)@ViewData["BlogCount"];
}
<p style="visibility:@(BlogCount > 0 ? "visible" : "hidden");" id="OldBlogs"><a class="btn btn-default" href="">View your old blogs</a></p>
```

You need to implement this code in your view (.cshtml). You will not required JavaScript code for hiding/showing the link.

Comment: OK, but I also need to change the value of BlogCount dynamically in my code-behind(in the controller), the code you have written is just a static value of BlogCount

Comment: OK, so I did that, but now I am getting a null reference exception, even though i set the value to 0

Comment: Can you show your Controller code. You should set data in `ViewData` like this `ViewData["BlogCount"] = 0;`. It is working as I have tested it.

Comment: Ok, nevermind, I made a mistake I added viewdata in a different actionresult. Fixed, thanks for the help!